# Can't install packages from CRAN: dbus errors

Tags: r, dbus, cran, install.packages

All of a sudden, I'm having issues install packages.  For example,

```
> install.packages("bayestestR")
Error: dbus: Call failed: Failed to activate service 'org.r_project.linux1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
> install.packages("deming")
Error: dbus: Call failed: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
>
```

If I run with `verbose=TRUE` or use a different repo, I get the same behavior.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Here's my system info:

```
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so;  LAPACK version 3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  datasets  grDevices utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_2.4.5 usethis_2.2.2  default_1.0.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] miniUI_0.1.1.1    compiler_4.3.1    crayon_1.5.2      promises_1.2.1   
 [5] Rcpp_1.0.11       bspm_0.5.1        stringr_1.5.0     callr_3.7.3      
 [9] later_1.3.1       fastmap_1.1.1     mime_0.12         R6_2.5.1         
[13] htmlwidgets_1.6.1 profvis_0.3.8     shiny_1.7.5       rlang_1.1.1      
[17] cachem_1.0.8      stringi_1.7.12    httpuv_1.6.11     fs_1.6.3         
[21] pkgload_1.3.3     memoise_2.0.1     cli_3.6.1         magrittr_2.0.3   
[25] ps_1.7.5          digest_0.6.33     processx_3.8.2    xtable_1.8-4     
[29] remotes_2.4.2.1   lifecycle_1.0.3   prettyunits_1.2.0 vctrs_0.6.3      
[33] glue_1.6.2        urlchecker_1.0.1  sessioninfo_1.2.2 pkgbuild_1.4.2   
[37] purrr_1.0.1       tools_4.3.1       ellipsis_0.3.2    htmltools_0.5.6.1
>
```

Comment: See [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/239489/372935)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at my `/var/log/syslog` file indicated it was a gpg key issue.

> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BAC6F0C353D04109

As a result, I used the first part of the instructions for setting up R on an ubuntu computer here: (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/)

Briefly

```
# update indices
sudo apt update -qq
# install two helper packages we need
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends software-properties-common dirmngr
# add the signing key (by Michael Rutter) for these repos
# To verify key, run gpg --show-keys /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc 
# Fingerprint: E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

This seemed to fix the problem.